# Tensor product of a representation and its dual

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Consider the common representation of $U(d)$ on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ as $U\otimes \ldots \otimes U$. As it commutes with all permutations $\pi \in S_n$, the space decomposes into irreps labeled $\lambda \in \rm{Par}(n,d)$.

I do realize that this may be a very stupid question, but how does this change for $U^{\otimes n/2} \otimes (U^* )^{\otimes n/2}$, where $n$ is even and $U^*$ is the conjugate (but not conjugate transpose) of $U$? Clearly, its no longer permutation symmetric but one could consider a non unitary representation that is as $(1/n!) \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \pi[U^{\otimes n/2} \otimes (U^*)^{\otimes n/2}]$.

How does this symmetrized representation decompose into irreps? Will this be exactly the same? Or will eg the symmetric subspace $\lambda = (n)$ decompose further? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $\pi\left[U^{\otimes n/2} \otimes \left(U^{\ast}\right)^{\otimes n/2}\right]$ ?

Comment: If $\pi$ is the unitary implementing the permutation of n copies of $\mathbb{C}^d$ then $\pi [U^{\otimes n/2} \otimes (U^* )^{\otimes n/2}] := \pi\left(U^{\otimes n/2} \otimes (U^* )^{\otimes n/2}\right)\pi^\dagger$ where $^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose. Sorry to be unclear.